# Ionic datetime min and max values

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework

i need to let the user select the start and the finish hour-time of a 2 work shifts.

morning shift: from 00:00 to 13:00

afternoon shift: from 13:00 to 24:00

A solution would be to set the hoursValue from 00 to 13 (for the morningShift for example) but the problem then would be that he could pick from 13: 01 - to 59 and i dont want that. He can only pick 13:00 MAX for the morning...
solution:

```
<ion-datetime 
    hourValues="00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13"
    [id]="i+'matF'"
    presentation="time"
    [(ngModel)]="shiftGroups[i].morningStart"
 ></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to allow users to select the start and finish times for two work shifts, a morning shift (from 00:00 to 13:00) and an afternoon shift (from 13:00 to 24:00). You're using Ionic's  component to handle the time selection. To ensure that the user can only select times up to 13:00 for the morning shift, you're on the right track by limiting the hourValues to 00-13.

Your current approach is a good start, but you can improve it by specifying the minuteValues to allow only 00 minutes for the morning shift. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
<ion-datetime 
hourValues="00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13"
minuteValues="00"
[id]="i+'matF'"
presentation="time"
[(ngModel)]="shiftGroups[i].morningStart"
```

> 

By adding minuteValues="00", you ensure that users can only select the minutes as 00 for the morning shift, which prevents them from selecting times beyond 13:00. This will give you the desired behavior for the morning shift. For the afternoon shift, you can similarly configure a separate  element with hourValues from 13 to 23 (if you want to include 13:00) or 14 to 23 (if you want to start from 13:01), and set minuteValues to "00" to allow only full hours for the start time of the afternoon shift.

By using this approach, you can effectively control the selection of shift start times while allowing the user to choose from the available options for each shift.

Comment: yes i thought about that but then i could only set the minutes to 00 while the user needs to pick whichever minutes he wants